# Access index of a leaflet marker

Tags: leaflet, popup, markers

I have seen some examples of this but they are not working for this situation.

What I need to be able to do is when I click on a marker get the index of that marker to write to the console. The reason I need this info is so that I can then go and later update the popup for this marker.

I have a JSBIN of this at http://jsbin.com/hepeli/4/edit?js,console,output

When you create a marker it makes a popup that displays an index, but this is actually just the length of an array that the markers are being pushed into.

When you click a marker with the delete tool it does write to console the index but I can't get it to do this when I just click on the marker.

Comment: are you saying you want to save the index as a property of the marker, not just the popup? just writing the index to the console is not that different from how you are writing it on delete: `console.log("added marker_index: " + markerList.indexOf(marker) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

starting from your code in onMapClickAddMarker:

```
markerList.push(marker);
```

add this

```
var marker_index = markerList.indexOf(marker);  
console.log("added marker_index: " + markerList.indexOf(marker) );
marker.myid = marker_index;      
marker.on('click', function(e) {
  console.log("Clicked marker with id: " + marker.myid);
});
```